# 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Firstly - I have scoured SO** and found many questions asking the same thing, though simply adding `<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />` in my web.config didn't cure the issue...

Ok, so I have started a new project, based on the template Angular SPA - link is here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83

I have upgraded the MVC to version 5 & the webApi to version 2 - to fall in line with other projects in the solution.

Now, in the _layout page of the SPA site I am trying to use the `@Html.ActionLink` helper, though keep getting the error `'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink`

I am sure this is all down to some web.config configuration - some kind of conflict between what packages I have installed and what is setup in the config from the template.

In particular, this part:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.WebPages.WebPage">
      <namespaces>            
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

If I change this to use version 5 then I get the error that the assembly (v5) could not be located etc.

I am running out of ideas on how to resolve this conflict.

Here are the config sections from my SPA web.config

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

If I change the version to 5, I get the error below:

```
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Development/IS/IS/IS.TransactionDesk.SPA/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\Development\IS\IS\IS.TransactionDesk.SPA\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Development\IS\IS\IS.TransactionDesk.SPA\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Darren\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Darren/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/3407d437/8e7ba9a/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Darren/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/3407d437/8e7ba9a/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Development/IS/IS/IS.TransactionDesk.SPA/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +37
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.DefaultTypeFactory(String typeName) +39
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateFactory(String typeName) +67
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfigCore(RazorWebSectionGroup config, String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +313
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +228
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath) +38
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig() +51
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost() +57
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host() +56
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode() +77
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +54
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +30
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9881909
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +43
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType) +28
   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +343
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance(IVirtualPathFactory factory, String virtualPath) +236
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +261
   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance(IVirtualPathFactory factory, String virtualPath) +132
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory) +58
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath) +59
   IS.TransactionDesk.SPA.Routing.DefaultRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) in d:\Development\IS\IS\IS.TransactionDesk.SPA\Routing\DefaultRouteHandler.cs:42
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +9598252
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm working with VS 2013 Pro Update 2. This is what worked for me:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete bin and obj folders
3. Reopen your solution and rebuild
4. No more errors on the view

BTW there is no need to change anything on configuration files and a simple clean and rebuild solution does not work.

Comment: This worked for me on VS 2012 PLUS deleting ASP.NET Temp files.

Comment: i wasted 2 hours on this thing. finally deleted bin and obj and voila. the solution built and ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning your solution, deleting the temporary ASP.NET files at

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.xxxx\Temporary ASP.NET Files

and rebuilding?

Comment: And does everything match in you packages.config file?  In the runtime section of your config you can try to add  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/> to change the old version of the assemply to the new

Comment: add to which dependentAssembly? - everything 'seems' to match, though it's all looking blurry now - been staring at it for a couple of hours now..

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Razor" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: That's the full code I use under runtime section of config to make sure the assemply is being used. I had a similar problem upgrading from Web API 1 ro Web API 2 a couple of weeks ago and that sorted it.

Comment: @Dan your workaround does not work for views inside areas. I added the "runtime" section to the web.config for the views on the area but no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed update 2 for Visual Studio 2013 and my problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on VS 2015 and i fix this problem.

You need to check your Views/Web.Config file if config file isn't exist you can copy an another project. After you need to change namespace on

-----** Views/Web.Config **---------

```
<namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="YourProjectName" />
</namespaces>
```

-----** Views/Web.Config **---------

if you have config file just check namespace name.