# 'System.Web.Webpages.Html.Htmlhelper' does not contain a definition for 'HtmlActionLink'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am facing above mention error for almost all HTML helper functions. Following are the config files of project. I am working on VS 2013 asp.net mvc framework 4.5. I have read other posts [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858199/system-web-webpages-html-htmlhelper-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-actionl) but can not get rid of this problem.

> /views/web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="fyp" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
            <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
            <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
        <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /><section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /></sectionGroup></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  <!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). --><legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" /><!-- When targeting ASP.NET MVC 3, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 and 2 references relink
             to MVC 3 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it.
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
         --></runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
        <settings>
            <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
            <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
        </settings>
    </system.net><dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging>
            <untrustedWebRequest>
                <whitelistHosts>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
                    <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
                </whitelistHosts>
            </untrustedWebRequest>
        </messaging>
        <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
        <reporting enabled="true" />
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. --><!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ --><openid>
        <relyingParty>
                <security requireSsl="false">
                    <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
                    <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>-->
                </security>
                <behaviors>
                    <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
                    <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
                </behaviors>
            </relyingParty></openid></dotNetOpenAuth><uri>
        <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
             which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
             It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
        <idn enabled="All" />
        <iriParsing enabled="true" />
    </uri></configuration>
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-->
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<!--
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    -->
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<!--
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
            <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
            <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
        <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /><section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /></sectionGroup></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpHandlers>
         <add path="routes.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="MvcCodeRouting.RouteDebugHandler, MvcCodeRouting" />
      </httpHandlers></system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  -->
<!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). -->
<!--<legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />-->
<!-- When targeting ASP.NET MVC 3, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 and 2 references relink
             to MVC 3 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it.
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
         -->
<!--</runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />-->
<!--//mssqllocaldb-->
<!--
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
        <settings>
            -->
<!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
<!--
            -->
<!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
<!--
        </settings>
    </system.net><dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging>
            <untrustedWebRequest>
                <whitelistHosts>
                    -->
<!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
<!--
                    -->
<!--<add name="localhost" />-->
<!--
                </whitelistHosts>
            </untrustedWebRequest>
        </messaging>
        -->
<!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
<!--
        <reporting enabled="true" />
    -->
<!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
<!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
<!--<openid>
        <relyingParty>
                <security requireSsl="false">
                    -->
<!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
<!--
                    -->
<!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>-->
<!--
                </security>
                <behaviors>
                    -->
<!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
<!--
                    <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
                </behaviors>
            </relyingParty></openid></dotNetOpenAuth><uri>
        -->
<!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
             which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
             It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
<!--
        <idn enabled="All" />
        <iriParsing enabled="true" />
    </uri><system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
         <add name="MvcCodeRouting.RouteDebugHandler" path="routes.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="MvcCodeRouting.RouteDebugHandler, MvcCodeRouting" />
      </handlers>
   </system.webServer></configuration>-->
```

Comment: Your `/Views/web.config` refers to `System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0,` but your `web.config` has `<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />` (although your commented out code does have `<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have commented the un-commented area and un-comment the commented one, now i am facing "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246'"

Comment: Too much code to go through, but its essentially a similar issue. You have a version mis-match somewhere in the config files - for example I can see something for `DotNetOpenAuth.Core` which has `newVersion="4.3.0.0"`